# Битрикс: Вывод описания каталога товаров в другом шаблоне

Tags: php, битрикс, компоненты, шаблоны

Компонент, в котором нужно вывести `DESCRIPTION` каталога товаров имеет имя `catalog.list`.

```
$arResult["DESCRIPTION"]
```

в нем не определен.
В $arResult в этом компоненте определен список товаров в этом каталоге.

Как мне заставить компонент брать еще и `DESCRIPTION`?

Компонента `catalog.section`, в котором `$arResult["DESCRIPTION"]` присутствует на странице каталога просто нет, потому что писал это все кто-то...

Comment: Очень маловероятно что на английском стеке вам ответят. Компонент самописный или нет? Я что-то такого в битриксе не нахожу

Comment: Понятия не имею, самописный или нет. Что делать в любом из этих случаев?

Comment: Дефолтный шаблон выводит описание? Если да, то попробуйте `<?
$res = CIBlockSection::GetByID(ID раздела);
$ar_res=$res->GetNext();
  echo $ar_res['DESCRIPTION'];
?>`